# Android - Why doesn't my axis draw?

Tags: android, path, line, draw

The following is supposed to draw an axis in the middle of the screen. However, nothing appears. I am positive that is has to do with my Paths.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //Variables declared here temporarily for testing purposes
    int canterX = getWidth() /2;
    int centerY = getHeight() /2;
    int radius = 150;    

    Path verticalAxis = new Path();
    Path horizontalAxis = new Path();

    drawAxis();
}

private void drawAxis(Canvas canvas) {
    int axisLineThickness = 1;
    int verticalEndX;
    int verticalEndY;
    int horizontalEndX;
    int horizontalEndY;

    Paint axisPaint = new Paint();
    axisPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    axisPaint.setStrokeWidth(axisLineThickness);

    double theta;

    for(int i = 90; i < 360; i += 180) {
        theta = toRadians(i);
        verticalEndX = centerX + (int) ((cos(theta)) * radius);
        verticalEndY = centerY + (int) ((sin(theta)) * radius);
        verticalAxis.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
        verticalAxis.lineTo(verticalEndX, verticalEndY);   
   }    
   canvas.drawPath(verticalAxis, axisColor);

   for(int i = 90; i < 360; i += 180) {
        theta = toRadians(i);
        horizontalEndX = centerX + (int) ((cos(theta)) * radius);
        horizontalEndY = centerY + (int) ((sin(theta)) * radius);
        horizontalAxis.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
        horizontalAxis.lineTo(verticalEndX, verticalEndY);   
   }    
   canvas.drawPath(horizontalAxis, axisColor);

}
```

I know I can make the axis draw if I add the following to the vertical and horizontal for loops respectively:

Vertical For Loop:

```
canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, verticalEndX, verticalEndY, paint);
```

Horizontal For Loop:

```
canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, horizontalEndX, horizontalEndY, paint);
```

But I don't want to solve the issue this way, I want to correct what is wrong with my paths. Can anyone tell me why the points aren't adding to my path correctly? The loop should only go through twice which creates a line for each side of the axis. Ie. One loop creates the top of the vertical axis and the second loop creates the bottom part.

How do I get my paths create that full line and then draw it outside of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint's default style appears to be FILL, so maybe just having a line in your path is confusing things.  Try setting it to STROKE:

```
axisPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

See [Paint.Style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that saves me from having to worry about many other paths that I might have had to fix. You don't happen to know why it doesn't work with fill do you? Or why having a line in the path confuses things?

Comment: Because when you only have 2 points in your path there's nothing to actually fill. :)  I suppose you could set it to FILL_AND_STROKE just in case, but it depends how explicit you're wanting to be.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to simply draw a couple of lines?  Since you're recalculating the path in each call to drawAxis anyway, I think drawLine would be slightly quicker and clearer.

Comment: Oh alright, yeah I will actually give `FILL_AND_STROKE` a try since I have to change the paint to fill something later anyways. The reason I didn't want to draw the line straight away was because I thought that it was an issue with how my paths were adding the points. (Later in the onDraw method I have many more paths that I set up in a similar way and hadn't tested them yet). So for the axis I could probably going ahead and just draw them, but not for other Paths that I have :) I appreciate the help brindy! Hope you check Android questions often because I'm sure I'll be back with more